# Cortana Skill only works for developer account that created it

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I built a bot in bot framework and provisioned it across Teams, in addition to the default of Skype and Web.
Then, I turned on the Cortana skill, and it worked for me for that channel.
Now, when I add users in testing via the deploy to group option, although they are able to select "Join Group", they're not actually able to use the Skill.
I tried this myself on my machine, but with a new outlook account and Cortana failed to invoke the skill.
Is there something about the accounts I add to the group that I need to configure?
These same users are able to use other skills that have been publicly published in Cortana.

Comment: The deploy to group function should work with any non-organizational email address which has been registered as a Microsoft account (https://signup.live.com). Outlook.com email addresses should work automatically. Will ask the engineering team if they are aware of any issues.

Comment: Irwin, I noticed you're hailing from Trinidad and Tobago; are the added users' locale set to [en-US](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills-faq)? Likewise for yourself, you may need to change your locale.

Comment: Hi @StevenG, yup, I had my users change their locale.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same condition. In the end I deleted the bot / skill and recreated it from the cortana dashboard (new skill) instead of directly via botframework dashboard - worked fine and group members could then access - strange as ultimately it ends up in the same place - perhaps it was more due to the recent updates on the MS sites.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently worked on a Cortana Skill, and deployed to a group for testing. You do not need to configure anything else besides providing the emails in the 'Deploy to group' option.

This however, works for MSA accounts only. Make sure that other members of your group are using their live/outlook account.